# CSS HTML Bottom fixed button jumps on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

does someone know how to avoid this behaviour? This button is simply set to: `position:fixed; bottom: 0;`

But then this behaviour appears as you can see in the picture.

[image]

On mobile while scrolling down top bar of the browser slides up and then my button  slides up too.

Comment: Without the code nobody can help you. I would check the height of the container.

Comment: If your browser set's it's bottom there, then you can't do anything.